# Is it better to style an element with multiple classes or with one CSS rule?

Tags: html, css

What can be more performant?

Let's say that i want to add this style to 10-15 elements of my page

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
user-select:none;
```

Is it better to put this in a class

```
.no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    user-select:none;
}
```

and then to put it in every element on the page like `<div class="myElement no-select"></div>`

or is it better if i use it to extend every element with sass/less like

```
.myElement{
    background-color:green;
    @extend .no-select;
}
```

and then in my html i would just have

This way the selector would be faster but the comiled css gets more and more bloated from duplicates.

Is it better to have a larger but more performant css, or smaller css file and more heavier and bloated with tons of classes html file?

Comment: are you looking for .myelement1, .myelement2, .myelement3{color: red} A selector like this?

Comment: Use classes as long they make sense: if some of your `.myelements` can't be selectable then two classes are perfectly fine.

Comment: Rather than worrying about the computer's performance--it can manage just fine, thank you--you should be worrying about YOUR OWN performance, in terms of how efficiently you and those that come after you can write, debug, understand, maintain, and extend the code. In that sense, isolating the non-selectable behavior into a `no-select` class seems clearly superior.

Comment: Use both! No, really. If you have 100 elements in a project might be hard to find them all and miserably paste into each class (or even to write `class=""` attributes to most), while it's much easier to add a chain of `#foo, #bar, .baz,` one line above your `.no-select {`. On the other hand after you get used to all you **helper** classes, one day you'll find your-self using a CSS collection of your-own, with a bunch of such classes (like the *Bootstrap fellas*) like `.clearfix` immediately while creating your HTML markup without even thinking.

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr): See [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Using a single class is more performant. So the fastest solution is:

```
.myElement{
    background-color:green;
}

.myElement-no-select {
    background-color:green;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    user-select:none;
}
```

and assign either `myElement` or `myElement-no-select` to a DOM node, depending whether you want the `no-select` styles or not.

That said, unless you have thousands of elements, you won't notice any difference. On top of that, if you need to toggle the `no-select` styles, then compressing the CSS in this way makes the JavaScript harder to maintain.

If you do the SASS compilation in JavaScript while the page loads, this step will probably be more expensive than what you gain by it. To actually bring the performance home, you need to compile the CSS once during deployment or packaging (so the server can serve a static file).

Comment: (Just an opinion, no bad feelings :) ) I think that in your example the `"myElement"` inside `.myElement-no-select` is just noise to a *Helper* class so misses the point. So yes, `.no-select` is good as that. Reusable later in the project or at any point. And helper classes should stay clean. What we can do instead is to chain, just one line above that helper class > other classes or IDs (ofc. always keeping an eye on *Specificity*.) and problem solved. Now, to chain or add directly that class into HTML? We'll leave that decision to the senses.